# pg_restore error could not execute query: ERROR: relation does not exist

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, postgresql-12

I am trying to restore, on the same server but different database, a specific table from a dump file using `pg_restore`. This table is located on `public` schema and I want to restore it on `public` schema too on different database.

Just for additional info, this server has some logical replication of some tables to Server A and physical replication for the whole database to Server B

Here is what I do:

First, do a backup with command:

```
pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -Fc --dbname=postgresql://postgres:passw@127.0.0.1:5432/db_personel > /backup-nfs/dump_dbpersonel_`date +\%d-\%m-\%y`.sql.
```

I am using a user called `postgres` to execute this command via `crontab`

Then I need to restore a particular table called "personel_data" to a newly created database called `"restored_tabel_profile"`. So I try some commands using user `root`:

```
root@db-profile-master:/# pg_restore -h 127.0.0.1 --data-only -- dbname=postgresql://postgres:pasww@127.0.0.1:5432/restored_tabel_profile --schema public --table personel_data < /backup-nfs/dump_dbpersonel_26-12-22.sql
root@db-profile-master:/# pg_restore -h 127.0.0.1 -a -d restored_tabel_profile -n public -t personel_data < /backup-nfs/dump_dbpersone_26-12-22.sql
root@db-profile-master:/# pg_restore -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres --data-only --dbname=postgresql://postgres:passw@127.0.0.1:5432/restored_tabel_profile --schema public --table personel_data < /backup-nfs/dump_dbpersonel_26-12-22.sql
```

I got this error:

> ```
> pg_restore: while PROCESSING TOC:
> pg_restore: from TOC entry 4764; 0 66030 TABLE DATA personel_data profile
> pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "public.personel_data" does not exist
> Command was: COPY public.personel_data (some colomns)  FROM stdin;
> pg_restore: warning: errors ignored on restore: 1`
> ```

If I use user `postgres` to restore like the following:

```
postgres@db-profile-master:/$ pg_restore -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres --data-only --dbname=postgresql://postgres:passw@127.0.0.1:5432/restored_tabel_profile --schema public --table personel_data < /backup-nfs/dump_dbpersone_26-12-22.sql
```

I got the same error as above.

I notice on the original database that the owner is a user called `profile`

1. What should I do to restore this particular table? I have access as `postgres` user but I do not have access as `profile` user.
2. Does it matter if I restore it on the server that has replications? Any implications?
3. Does it matter to restore a database using user `postgres` if the database is owned by a user other than `postgres`?

Comment: Well, the `--data-only` parameter does exactly that: it restores the data into an existing table. If you want to use `--data-only` you must create the table manually before importing the data. If you want `pg_restore` to create the table, remove the `--data-only` parameter

Comment: oh, well. You are correct @a_horse_with_no_name. remove the `--data-only` and it works like a charm. But why the size shrinks so significantly compared to the original size? The restored table has only 5.5Gb while the original has 27Gb.